# Вывести 0 (ноль) в поле input с помощью php

Tags: php, input

Доброй ночи, в программировании не слишком силен, только учусь самостоятельно и поэтому возник вопрос. Есть абстрактная функция:

```
$options['settings'] = 0;
```

Которая выводится в поле input таким образом:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if ($options['settings']) print $options['settings']; ?>" />
```

На странице цифра 0 пишется в форму, но при обновлении не запоминается и поле остается пустым. Про ноль в PHP читал и не могу понять как его вывести в этом поле. Все остальные цифры и числа при обновлении остаются, а ноль ни в какую не поддается...

Прошу помощи!)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$options['settings']?>" />
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает)

@shorty пояснил как это работает, ему тоже благодарность)

Answer (score 1):

Поясняя ответ @Qwertiy.

В PHP есть такая штука, как нестрогое сравнение. Условные конструкции (if, while) принимают на вход значения любого типа, а не только булевого, и в этом случае значение *приводится* к булевому типу. `0`, [по философии PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php) - это синоним `false`, поэтому условие не проходит. Для того, чтобы оно прошло, достаточно выполнить вышеуказанную проверку ии проверку на несоответствие перменной `null` (`if (isset($settings['options']))`).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <?php if ($options['settings']) print $options['settings']; ?>
> ```

```
<?php if ($options['settings'] || $options['settings']===0) print $options['settings']; ?>
```

Comment: Применил Ваш вариант, но значение все равно не сохраняется...

Comment: `==="0"`? Что там вообще находится, когда оно не выводится?

Comment: пустое поле остается

Answer (score 0):

Поясняя ответ @MAXOPKA,

В программировании есть такая штука, как здравый смысл.
Который заключается, в частности, в том, чтобы не совершать тех действий, которые не нужны. 
В данном случае проверка `if ($options['settings'])` не несет абсолютно никакого смысла, и ее можно выбросить, решив тем самым, все проблемы с нулём, и заодно упростив код.

Так же, нет ни малейшей причины писать `<?php print`. Вместо этого гораздо удобнее написать `<?=`.

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение! Это действительно работает)